# Div with Span in td

Tags: css, html

I have a table which looks like this ...

```
<td>
<div style="float:left">
<img src="image1.png" style="display:block" /><br>
<img src="image2.png" />
</div>
<span> <input type="input" />
</td>


<td>
<div style="float:left">
<img src="image1.png" style="display:block" /><br>
<img src="image2.png" />
</div>
<span> <input type="input" />
</td>
```

I have set `style=float` to make the images and the input field in line.

But the problem is when I resize the brower, the `div` floats over the `td` which I don't want to have.

Is there any workaround for that problem??

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly** you have to check your html, close those tags (`<span></span>`) ;)

**Secondly**, when items are floating, the container will not read the height, so you have to add a clearer div underneath the floating items.

```
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
```

**Example**:

```
    <td>
    <div style="float:left">
    <img src="image1.png" style="display:block" /><br>
    <img src="image2.png" />
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <span> <input type="input" /> </span>
    </td>


    <td>
    <div style="float:left">
    <img src="image1.png" style="display:block" /><br>
    <img src="image2.png" />
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <span> <input type="input" /> </span>
    </td>
```

Comment: After this.. the images and input dont stay inline.. input moves to the next row.. :((

Comment: add you code to jsfiddle.com , so i can have a better look what you want to achieve. :)